# Best Approach Towards Extracting Large Quantities of PDF files?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, ssis, 7zip

I'm attempting to improve the performance behind an automation workflow that extracts several zip files(10 to 15), each containing roughly 5,000 PDF files.

My question is: **If I want to extract all these zip files quickly into one directory, what is your recommended best approach**? What if I wanted to archive these files first and then copy the output to a separate directory for post-processing?

My initial thoughts were to run each zip file through 7za.exe(7-zip) in parallel, which I have done manually in the past. However, it is still extremely slow and can take up to two hours. Whether I run the extraction process one at a time or all at once does not appear to affect performance.

I will be recreating this workflow in C# and T-SQL. **The goal is to take SSIS out of the picture for better input validation and logic before the data reaches our database**. Here is a screenshot of the zip extraction section of the current automation.

[image: Current Automation Workflow]

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: After a very quick google search, I found a bunch of questions here on SO that deal with how to speed up file decompression. Try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647910/fastest-way-to-extract-zip-archive and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502001/a-faster-way-of-decompressing-a-large-zip-file

Comment: @digital.aaron Yea, I looked at those links prior to making this post. Unfortunately, they are not what I'm looking for. One has broken blog links to the reference and the other is the workflow process I'm already currently running. Thank you though!

Comment: Have you tried pigz? There's a Windows port available: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/pigz-for-windows.html

Comment: @digital.aaron I have not. I will give it a try. Thank you!